# What is the proper way to pull information from database and display it in columns?

Tags: multiple-columns

I am in a WordPress environment and need to pull posts from the database and display it according to the layout needed.  This would be very simple if the data is static but it is not so I am not sure what is the best way that is browser compatible.

So the data is pulled and needs to display in 3 columns from left to right, top to bottom and know when to increase the height when needed.

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve. http://postimage.org/image/nsyq7rsgh/

As you can see the data begins in the first column going from top to bottom and when it runs out of room, it goes to the next column and so on.  But the twist here is that when it runs out of room on the last column, it needs to know to jump down back to first column and repeat.  So how is this possible with dynamic content?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for awhile to an answer for this, I came across this plugin here -> http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

It solves my issues with columnizing my page which is browser compatible.